# Angular js directive dynamic template binding

Tags: templates, angularjs, dynamic, directive

I have a template which looks like:

```
scope:{
  localClickFunc: "&click",
  myLocalDbClickFunc: "&dblclick"
} ...

 <myButton  ng-click="localClickFunc($event)" ng-doubleckick="myLocalDbClickFunc($event)"/>
```

there are many other events (mouseover  etc)

my localClickFunc are binded in scope directive with controller functions(they could be binded with "=" for my case It doesn't matter).

**The problem is that in the usage of this 'myButton' directive not all attributes are necessary** .If I use it with  all the other events will get registered and fired through angular to a noop function.

I can have as many as 1000 buttons on the screen .What would be the solution to this ?. Are there conditional templates ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `?` in the scope binding definition makes the attribute optional.

However, function bindings (`&`) are always optional, as far as Angular is concerned. I.e. Angular will not complain if you do not specify a function in this binding and it will put a function in the scope of the directive anyway. So you cannot write `if( scope.localClickFunc == null )` to check for its existence.

I would suggest to use the optional binding `=?` to specify the callbacks. This way you will be able to check the scope for the existence of the binding and, only if it exists, bind it to the actual DOM event. Example code:

```
scope:{
    localClickFunc: "=?click",
    localDbClickFunc: "=?dblclick"
},
link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
    ...
    if( scope.localClickFunc != null ) {
        element.on("click", scope.localClickFunc);
    }
    ...
}
```

Then use the directive as:

```
<myButton click="localClickFunc($event)"
          dblclick="myLocalDbClickFunc($event)"
/>
```

You can specify any or all of the attributes and the handlers will be installed accordingly.

Comment: how can I turn that on-click  to an ng click ?

Comment: Why would you want to do that? Perhaps the edit clarifies the intended usage.

Comment: you mean <myButton click="externFunction" ...>. What I want is to conditionally add directives . I am seeing now the compile function if I can use it without performance impact on 1000 buttons

Comment: Perhaps you should also investigate setting a single event listener in the parent element of your list. This solution solves the "dont set noop handlers if the handler is not specified" problem.

Comment: @NikosParaskevopoulos I see you have experience and interest in angular , can you tell me what will I lose if I switch to element.on('on') instead of using the angular ng-click?

Comment: You will have to call `$scope.$apply()` for events bound outside of Angular. Other than that, I don't think there will be any other loss. Prefer to call `$scope.$apply(function(){ /*your code*/})` instead of `your_code;$scope.$apply()`, as the former handles thrown exceptions correctly with respect to Angular.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38966/discussion-between-ovidiu-buligan-and-nikos-paraskevopoulos)

Answer (score 0):

u can send the attr like say the directive name is mydir then  and then in the link and compile functions one of the 3rd parameter is usually names as params and u get there by params.mydir (value will be ovidiu). you can send anything textbased like ';' seperated like "click;dbclick;onmouseout" and break it in the directive with params.mydir.split(';'). from there you can even go to groups of events like "allClicks", u just need in the link some dictionary or switch that will append the right stuff.